# How to know result type with Task.whenAllComplete with multiple types of data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, task

I want to call a couple of tables in Firestore and collect all the info, to parse and send it back to view.

So I have somthing like: (example)

```
val cities = mutableListOf<City>()
val users = mutableListOf<User>()

val tasks = mutableListOf<Task<QuerySnapshot>>()
val q1 = database
    .collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("place.city", cityName)
    .get()

val q2 = database
    .collection("users")
    .whereEqualTo("city", cityName)
    .get()

tasks.add(q1)
tasks.add(q2)

Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks)
      .addOnCompleteListener { allTask->
           allTask.forEach{ task->
               // transform into the list of its corresponding model
           }
       }
```

And the problems arrives, that I dont know how to know the "origin" of the task to parse the snapshot into de corresponing model.

How can I determine which model I have to use, based on the result task?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to know the "origin" of the task"? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: If I do the calls alone, I know I'll get a snapshot that is a list of Cities, and another that is a list of Users . But if I call into a Task, (to get all the info at same time),I do not know how to distinguish which snapshot is to know how to transform the information into the corresponding model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting as an argument, is a List of objects. To know which one is an object of the corresponding type, you need to check if the object is an instance of a particular class, as in the following lines of code:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<List<Any>> { list ->
    for (obj in list) {
        if (obj is City) {
            val city = (obj as DocumentSnapshot).toObject(City::class.java)
        } else if (obj is User) {
            val user = (obj as DocumentSnapshot).toObject(User::class.java)
        }
    }
})
```